# How do I specify the characters Vim should use for increasing and decreasing the indent?

Tags: vim

I'm working with a language (FileMaker calculations) that uses `(` and `[` for blocks of code. I want to have C-style indenting but using these characters instead of `{`. I've tried editing `cinkeys` (`:set cinkeys=(,0),[,0],o,O`) without success both with `cindent` on and off.

Is this possible with `cindent` or do I have to go to `indentexpr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method with `cinkeys` should work as long as you are one indentation level in with a `{`. Here is what the vim documentation says about cinkeys indentation:

```
Note that 'cindent' indenting does not work for every code scenario.  Vim
is not a C compiler: it does not recognize all syntax.  One requirement is
that toplevel functions have a '{' in the first column.  Otherwise they are
easily confused with declarations.
```

If this does not meet your needs you will have to use [indentexpr](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27indentexpr%27).